# What is the common way to save data in a database stucture in the ubuntu sdk

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-sdk, development, database

I plan to write an ubuntu app that runs on all ubuntu mobile devices as well on the ubuntu desktop. In this app i have to save some things onto the hard disk via database.

What is the common way to do this? I tried to find something in the ubuntu sdk documentation i was not successful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a couple of options here, either use [U1DB](https://developer.ubuntu.com/api/apps/qml/current/U1db/) which stores json documents in a sqlite database and has good documentation. Or you can use [Qt's Local Storage module](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-localstorage-qmlmodule.html) which you can interact directly with a sqlite database.

Comment: If i want to use Qt's Local Storage module . What app armor policy do i need? I tryed all of them but i cannot get access to create the database.

Comment: You shouldn't need any apparmor permissions for qt local storage. Just make sure your applicationName in your MainView matches the app name in your click manifest file.

Comment: Adding in Main view applicationName : "<APP_ID of manifest>" resolved the problem.